# On up or down press, animate page up/down for 100% of viewport height

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to speed up the default down/up behavior when pressing up or down. The whole page should animate up or down. How can I do that?

My code:

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      switch(e.which) {
          case 38: // up
            $('html').animate({ scrollTop: $('html').scrollTop()-500 }, 250);
          break;
          case 40: // down
            $('html').animate({ scrollTop: $('html').scrollTop()+500 }, 250);
          break;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('html').scrollTop()-500 }, 250);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scroll the viewport height and not the whole page use `$(window).height()`

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var $body = $('body');
      switch(e.which) {
          case 38: // up
            $body.animate({ scrollTop: $body.scrollTop() - $(window).height() }, 250);
            console.log()
          e.preventDefault();
          break;
          case 40: // down
            $body.animate({ scrollTop: $body.scrollTop() + $(window).height() }, 250);
          e.preventDefault();
          break;
      }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Got it. Almost.

The problem now is that the preventdefault should only apply to the up/down keys...

```
 $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var $body = $('body');
      switch(e.which) {
          case 38: // up
            $body.animate({ scrollTop: $body.scrollTop() - $body.height() }, 250);
            console.log()
          break;
          case 40: // down
            $body.animate({ scrollTop: $body.scrollTop() + $body.height() }, 250);
          break;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: That will scroll the whole page not the view port height, you are aware of that right?